# Trouble with libraries (Remix)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging, library

Tried out libraries for the first time, had a really bad experience with them. I need some help in getting my contracts to work between libraries.

Library 1:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

library IntExtended{

    function increment(uint _self) returns (uint){
        return _self+1;
}

    function decrement(uint _self) returns(uint){
        return _self-1;
}

    function incrementByValue(uint _self,uint _value) returns (uint){
        return _self + _value;
}

    function decrementByValue(uint _self,uint _value) returns (uint){
        return _self -_value;
}

    }
```

File that works with it, I don't know what you call it, second library?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "browser/Library.sol";

contract TestLibrary{
    using IntExtended for uint;

    function testIncrement(uint _base) returns (uint){
        return IntExtended.increment(_base);
}

    function testDecrement(uint _base) returns (uint){
        return IntExtended.decrement(_base);
}

    function testIncrementByValue(uint _base,uint _value) returns(uint){
        return _base.incrementByValue(_value);
} 

    function testDecrementByValue(uint _base, uint _value) returns (uint){
        return _base.decrementByValue(_value);
}
}
```

The library `IntExtended` is not functioning, however, the contract referencing to IntExtended is functioning.

Comment: `return IntExtended.increment(_base)` should be `return _base.increment()`, right? And what do you mean by your last sentence? What exactly is working and what's not? (And for the stuff that's not working, what exactly does that mean? Do you get an error? An incorrect result?)

Comment: Changed it to  _base. , no difference. When deploying the IntExtended, and trying to execute would result in... transact to IntExtended.decrement errored pending ... transact to IntExtended.decrementByValue errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code. Your comment seems to have been mangled, and it's hard to reproduce your error without the corrected code.

Comment: Oh, it looks like perhaps you're trying to deploy the library by itself and then call it? I don't think that's expected to work.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, can't edit comments for 5 minutes. You can't execute libraries? Oh good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You have no uint defined in your storage to use the library on, also your library functions can be pure.

below `using IntExtended for uint`

add

```
uint myUint
```

and then you can call the library functions like

```
myUint.increment()
```

or `_base.increment()`

Edit: Spun it up in remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

library IntExtended{

    function increment(uint _self) returns (uint){
        return _self+1;
    }
}


contract TestLibrary{
    using IntExtended for uint;

    function testIncrement(uint _base) returns (uint){
        return _base.increment();
    }
}

0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 decoded input  {
    "uint256 _base": "5"
}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "uint256: 6"
}
```

Comment: transact to IntExtended.decrementByValue pending ... 
transact to IntExtended.decrementByValue errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information. {Received the same error}

Comment: See edited answer for example :)